# Django internal server error due to a typecasted value in objects.get query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am working on the server side of an application in python for which I have a method to upload `key pair` to a database table as follows:

```
def add_ube_keys(request):
    key_data = json.loads(request.body)
    user_id  = key_data['user_id']

    try:
        owner = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        for i in key_data['keys']:
                recipient = User.objects.get(id=long(i))
                print recipient.id

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print 'Owner id not found'

    return_data = {
        'success':True
    }
    rdata = json.dumps(return_data)
    return HttpResponse(rdata, content_type='application/json')
```

Basically in the `for loop` the `i` is of `<type 'unicode'>` which I have typecasted to `long` in the query statement `recipient = User.objects.get(id=long(i))`,  but this works fine for a few iterations and then `terminates with a 500 internal error`, it doesn't raises the `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception. If I executed the same query with a harcoded integer value then it never fails, what could be the reason for such behaviour.

In case it is relevant then the table structure is as follows:

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| owner_id    | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| receiver_id | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sk          | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The sample json format of `key_data` is:

```
{
  'user_id': 1
  'keys':{
           '1': string1
           '2': string2
         }
}
```

Comment: what is `i` ? something like `1.0`, `2.2` ?

Comment: @doniyor `i` iterates over the integer values stored in `unicode` in the `key_data['keys']` object, which is basically used to refer to user id in the databse table.

Comment: @AjayGupta thanks a lot for your help, stacktrace helped me detect a bug on client side which was sending 0 based user ids whereas server works on 1 based. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you are decoding the request properly?  Add some print lines into your code.

Take out the try/except and print each iteration of that for loop to see what i equates to.  My guess is that you are not getting what you think you are.

edit:  This is what I meant

```
def add_ube_keys(request):
    key_data = json.loads(request.body)
    owner = User.objects.get(id=key_data['user_id'])

    for i in key_data['keys']:
        print(i)
        recipient = User.objects.get(id=long(i))
        print recipient.id
```

This way you can see what is being send to you User.objects.get query.

Comment: Yeah I added the `try except` block around the statement, but it is not raising any exceptions. There is already a `print recipient.id` statement which works for a few iterations correctly after which the function fails.